# How to reuse this code instead of copying and pasting it again and again

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, code-reuse

I have an array of objects and the object contains data members such as GoalsFor , GoalsAgainst and MatchPoints. Now I have the search and display the data using binary search method for a given goalsFor  or goalsAgainst or MatchPoints value .
I am making a binary search class to do the searching operation but at present i have to make three of binary search classes one for each data member of object for the three operations .Is there a way I can reuse the binary search code instead of copying it thrice.

This is a homework problem but i am assumming my doubt is more general.
Constraint : Linear search not allowed and no built in function except i/o can be used

```
public class BinarySearchPoints
{
  public static void search(Teams arr[], int searchValue, int start , int end)

  {
    if(start > end)
        return;
    int mid = (end + start ) / 2;
    if(searchValue == arr[mid].points)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[mid].toString());
        search(arr, searchValue, mid + 1, end); 
        search(arr, searchValue, start, mid - 1);
    }
    else if(searchValue < arr[mid].points)
        {
            search(arr, searchValue, mid + 1, end);
        }
    else
        search(arr, searchValue, start, mid - 1);

  }
}
```

the only thing i am changing in other implementations of binary search is using goalsFor and Goals against instead of points

Comment: you can implement your binary search logic as java function and then call that function multiple times

Comment: Can you show this code that gets copied thrice?

Comment: Please post one copy of your binary search code so it's easier to explain what needs to be changed.

Comment: Short answer:  Yes.  Longer answer: the devil is in the details; the details of the code will determine ways to abstract it.  You may want to look into the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface too.

Comment: You may want to consider a non-recursive implementation of `binarySearch`, it's somewhat more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely generalize your binary search method.

First thing to do is to consider what your binary search needs from the collection of data passed into it. It turns out that the only thing it needs is an ability to compare a data element to a search value.

Next thing is to come up with a way to express comparison in an abstract way, e.g. as an interface. Your interface would have a single method that answers the question "Where is element `X` with respect to the given number"?

You can express it in Java as a generic interface:

```
interface ElementComparator<E> {
    // This assumes that you always search for an int property
    int compare(E element, int value);
}
```

Your compare method needs to return negative value if `E`'s attribute is less than `V`, a positive value if it is greater than `V`, and zero if the two are equal. `V` must implement `Comparable` interface.

Now your `binarySearch` method could be defined as follows:

```
T binarySearch<E>(
    Collection<E> data
,   int value
,   ElementComparator<E> comparator
) {
    ...
}
```

To decide whether to go right or left of the middle you need to call `comparator.compare(data.get(mid), value);` and check the result.

Now you can call your `binarySearch` like this:

```
List<Teams> list = ...
Teams fivePoints = binarySearch(list, 5, new ElementComparator<Teams>() {
    public int compare(Teams element, int value) {
        return Integer.compare(element.points, value);
    }
});
Teams fiveAgainst = binarySearch(list, 5, new ElementComparator<Teams>() {
    public int compare(Teams element, int value) {
        return Integer.compare(element.against, value);
    }
});
```

Note how the comparison callback is supplied inline with the call: this is where the magic happens - when `binarySearch` implementation wants to compare a `Team` with `value`, it calls `compare`, which in turn calls `Integer.compare` on `element.points` or `element.against`, depending on the callback.